# Unable to inject using guice

Tags: guice

I have an archive class having the following structure:

```
public class Archive implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener{

    @Inject
    private Configuration configuration;
    public static final String FF = "ff";

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext arg1)
            throws Exception {

        System.out.println("in execute method :)");
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }


    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution arg0) {
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution arg0) {
        JobExecution jobExecution = arg0.getJobExecution();
         ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
         Properties properties = configuration.getPrefixProperties(FF);
         filePath =  properties.getProperty("fd.folder");
         fileName = "test.csv";

    }
}
```

My binder class looks like this:

```
@Singleton
public class EWM extends AbstractModule {

    @Inject
    private static Injector injectorInstance;

    private static final EWM instance = new EWM();

    public static final EWM getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Injector getInjector() {
        return injectorInstance;
    }

    public EWM() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {    
        bind(Archive.class);
        requestInjection(LoggingAspect.class);  
    }
}
```

I am getting null configuration object. I can't figure out the reason why configuration is null. Can somebody help me finding out the reason .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not enough information in your question to answer it, but I can give you some suggestions on where to look.

Guice tries to prevent injection of null, so it's likely that Archive isn't getting injected at all. There are a couple of reasons that could happen:

- Archive has an `@Inject` constructor that doesn't set the `configuration` field

  - Guice would probably choose to inject this constructor rather than the `@Inject` fields if both are available. Remove the `@Inject` annotation from the constructor.
- Whomever is instantiating Archive isn't Guice.

  - Are you using `Injector#getInstance()` to instantiate Archive directly, is it transitively a field on something that is being instantiated by the injector?

Comment: If a class has a constructor annotated with `@Inject` and fields annotated with `@Inject` , Guice will create the object using the annotated constructor then inject the fields annotated with `@Inject`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the reason why `configuration` is null is because **the class isn't being created by Guice**.

To prevent that, **give classes that are designed to be created by Guice a package-scope or private constructor**:

```
public class Archive implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {
  private static final String FF = "ff";
  private final Configuration configuration;

  @Inject
  Archive(Configuration configuration) {
    this.configuration = configuration;
  }

  ...
```

I chose a package-scope constructor because I would want to write unit tests for the class (see the notes, below).

If you want `Archive` to be a singleton, annotate the class with `@Singleton`

Here is a simple module for the above class:

```
public class ArchiveModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(Archive.class);
  }
}
```

The `bind()` call isn't really needed--nor is the module actually--but I like having it so I know that if the module is installed, Guice will give an error at injector creation time if it cannot create the dependencies for the `Archive` class.

In your main you would have code that looked something like this:

```
Main main = Guice.createInjector(
    new ArchiveModule(),
    new AnotherModule(),
    ... );
main.run();
```

Some notes:

- Adding @Singleton to your module has no effect because Guice doesn't construct the modules; the code that asks Guice to create the injector generally constructs the modules.
- Similarly, your modules are not injected, so the `injector` field of your module will never be set (unless you request static injection on the module, but I strongly recommend against that)
- Prefer constructor injection over field injection so 1) your fields can be final, 2) you can write unit tests that create your objects without using Guice, and 2) it's hard to accidentally create the class in production code without Guice.
- I recommend not using abbreviations for class names unless the abbreviation is well-known